# Track which process uses Bonjour service on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bonjour, zeroconf

Bonjour service used to take almost nothing. But it recently takes 10-20% of CPU almost all the time.

The problem is resolved by simply terminate the Bonjour service, but there should be a reason why it takes so much CPU. I guess there should be another process that depends on Bonjour service heavily but I have no idea to figure out who uses Bonjour service.

Is there a way to track which process/program uses Bonjour service?

Comment: Try Process Monitor from Microsoft SysInternals.  Start it and filter for Bonjour.   I have that service running but it is not doing anything.

Comment: Also if you have iTunes running, uninstall in this order: iTunes
Quick Time
Apple Software Update
Apple Mobile Device Support
Bonjour
Apple Application Support .   Then restart and check, Reinstall iTunes if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can track. You can download a tool named Process explorer from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Process explorer is a tool to track what resources, DLLs and programs are used by another process. After installing, run it, and expand processes to know what they are using with other properties.

Or you can install process monitor that will display the file system and registry activity of the filtered application.